# Why is my Model.find returning nothing?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm very new to node and sequelize and I'm trying to follow this [short introduction](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.0/articles/getting-started).

I've worked through the parts to connect to my database (postgres). I've also defined a model:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  password: Sequelize.STRING
});
```

I have succesfully synchronized the scheme and created instances. But when I attempt to read from the database using this:

```
User
  .find({ where: { username: 'john-doe' } })
  .then(function(err, johnDoe) {
    if (!johnDoe) {
      console.log('No user with the username "john-doe" has been found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Hello ' + johnDoe.username + '!');
      console.log('All attributes of john:', johnDoe.get());
    }
  });
```

That instance does exist, but I only ever see the 'No user with...' message. The query it generates seems correct and when I try it manually, the returned results are what I would expect to see.

Using the same query I can do this, which also works:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM my_user_table where username='john-doe'", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(function(items) {
    // We don't need spread here, since only the results will be returned for select queries
    console.log(items);
  });
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you was too close. But you must not use an argument for error handling on `then` method.

So you must use like the following;

```
User
  .findOne({ where: { username: 'john-doe' } })
  .then(function(johnDoe) {
    if (!johnDoe) {
      console.log('No user with the username "john-doe" has been found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Hello ' + johnDoe.username + '!');
      console.log('All attributes of john:', johnDoe.get());
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up promises and node-style callbacks.  Typically you only expect `(err, results)` when you pass a callback to the original function.  If you call `then`, you are working with promises and should only expect results.  You should call `catch` to get any errors.

```
User
  .find({ where: { username: 'john-doe' } })
  .then(function(johnDoe) {
    if (!johnDoe) {
      console.log('No user with the username "john-doe" has been found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Hello ' + johnDoe.username + '!');
      console.log('All attributes of john:', johnDoe.get());
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // Error handling here
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, spot on.Accepting the first answer which was also correct